# Can I greet my boss with "Hey, boss"

Tags: management, employer-relations, manager

I mean, I just want to make the conversation more friendly, so sometimes I greet my boss with "Hey boss" or "thanks, boss".

Is it ok?

Comment: Ask him, not us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that depends. If your workplace is pretty casual and your boss doesn't mind, then sure. I greet my boss the same way, but that's part of the organizational culture here.

Comment: That's what I thought, too. My boss is relaxed, easy-going, I'd say, but if he does mind, he doesn't show it ;)

Comment: Then you should be good to go :) I'm fairly certain that if he DID mind, you'd already know

Comment: yeah, right on ;-)